# Is there a name given to functions that map from real numbers to complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Consider a function $f(x)$ which takes in real-valued inputs and remaps them to complex valued outputs. I know that a *complex function* is a function from complex numbers to complex numbers, but is there a name given to functions that map from real numbers to complex numbers? An example of such a function is given below,

Let $F(n)$ represent the $nth$ Fibonacci number in which $n \in \mathbb{R}$, $F(n)$ is then given by,

$$F(n) = \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\frac{cos(n\pi)}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \right)^n \right]-\frac{sin(n\pi)}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \right)^ni$$

Comment: You want a complex-valued function of a real variable?

Comment: Well, You can call them Complex valued function of real variables.

Comment: @Peter I think he is just asking for the nomenclature.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana Yes, I haven't studied maths at the university level so I didn't know the nomenclature for it

Comment: Fibonacci numbers are real

Comment: Provided the domain of $f$ is an interval, you may $f$ call a *path*.